# jquery how to hide-sidebar and remove class when clicked somewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

ihave  a jquery code that works to show the offcanvas sidebar and also makes the page opacity lower by toggling the class acive main-wrapper class.
this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-icon').on('click', function(){
       $('.offcanvas').toggleClass('is-open');
       $('.main-wrapper').toggleClass('active');
    }); // end of on click     
}); // end of ready
```

what i want is how i could remove those two toggled classes when clicked any where on the page except .nav-icon class.
and this is the html code.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
        <div id="offCanvasLeft" class="offcanvas" aria-hidden="true">
            <ul class="nav menus flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">artists</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- off-canvas-wrapper -->


    <nav class="navbar">

        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    </nav>

    <div id="main-section" class="container">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the event parameter to the .on() handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav-icon').on('click', function(){
       $('.offcanvas').toggleClass('is-open');
       $('.main-wrapper').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('html').on('click', function(event){
        if(!$(event.target).hasClass('nav-icon'))
        {
            $('.offcanvas').removeClass('is-open');
            $('.main-wrapper').removeClass('active');         
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using event delegation, you'd set up a click event on the `document` that responds to any element except the `.nav-icon` and that event handler would simply apply a class that sets `disply:none` to `.nav-icon`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-icon').on('click', function(){
       $('.offcanvas').toggleClass('is-open');
       $('.main-wrapper').toggleClass('active');
    }); // end of on click   
    
    // When anything on the page is clicked excpet ".nav-icon"...
    $(document).on("click", "div:not(.nav-icon)", function(){
       // Hide ".nav-icon"
       $(".nav-icon").addClass("hidden");
    });        
}); // end of ready
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }

.nav-icon {
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:10px;
}

.nav {
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="nav-icon">I'm .nav-icon</div>
  <div class="nav">I'm not .nav-icon</div>
</body>
```